# Hot to make invisible "placeholder" in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, placeholder

I am trying to make invisible placeholder in Internet Explorer,
I've used color: transparent and opacity:0 but its not working just in IE.

I need to put the placeholder because I am using some code that need it even when is transparent to make it work.

hope someone can help me,
thnks

I have tried color: transparent but it doesn't work

```
  &::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the placeholder invisible, you could directly remove the placeholder property.

Besides, you could try to use the following code to set the placeholder color (change the color to **transparent**):

```
<style>

    ::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
        color: red; /*color:transparent;*/
        opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
    }

    :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
        color: red; /*color:transparent;*/
    }

    ::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
        color: red; /*color:transparent;*/
    }
</style>
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
```

[image]